# Limit the max number of rows in column MySQL

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, limit, rows

I have searched for a while now how to limit the number max number of rows in a table

I have made a registration system in phpmyadmin and when I come up to 60 users then no one can register anymore.

Hope this information helps, and I hope that you can help me!

I use phpmyadmin.

Here is a picture of what I want to limit to max 60 users to make it more clearer:

[image]

Comment: You can do this using an `insert` trigger that counts the number of rows in the table and errors (or deletes a row) when the limit would be exceeded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TRIGGER check_user_number 
BEFORE INSERT ON users FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN
      IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users) >= 60
      THEN
           CALL 'Cannot add row, the number of users is limited to 60!';
      END IF;
 END;
```